# how do i assign values to shapes to be displayed in my map

Tags: qgis

I apologize for the simplistic nature of this question, I'm VERY new to QGIS. I'm trying to use QGIS to display political information. I have a map of my state, with each town as it's own shape. I have an ID for each town/shape. What I want to do is assign a value to each town/shape, and have a scaled display of these values by town/shape.

Can anyone help me with the process for assigning values to each town/shape?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a new column and input the values manually.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#sec-attribute-table

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to figure out what I need from here. And the attribute table is not allowing me to add a new column. Am I able to take an xls or cvs that has values associated with each shape, and apply them to the map? For example, since I'm using political data, I'd like to see the number of votes from each town. Thanks!!

Comment: First, yes it does http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/best-way-to-add-attribute-data-to-a-shape-file/6840#6840. Second, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis

Comment: In order that your attribute table alloes you to ad a column (and add data too) it must be in edit mode