# How to import multiple shapefiles without any dbf to a PostGIS database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, dbf

I have a polyline shapefile (.shp and .shx) without .dbf. I would like to import the shp into PostGIS.

In order to do that, I created the corresponding .dbf using the r code provided by mdsumner in this post  [Adding Attribute data to shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/best-way-to-add-attribute-data-to-a-shape-file)

The .dbf consists of just one row, while the .shp corresponds to a polyline.

Now, if I load the shp into QGIS, the attribute table lists the features ids of the polyline in read-only mode.
I know that I could save the file loaded in QGIS then I would be able to import it into PostGIS.

However I have thousands of similar shapefiles and I would like to import all of them into PostGIS. I suppose that this is not possible because the .dbf is read-only because I got this message: "dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened".

I read in another post, that it is the shx file that connects the shp to the dbf but this did not help me.

Apologies if the question is not relevant or it is not the correct way to proceed.

Comment: "the shx file that connects the shp to the dbf" - that's incorrect.  The SHX file is an index to the location of shapes within the SHP file, in case you want to, say, go to the 100th shape directly rather than reading the 99 prior ones.

Comment: DBF should have a row for each shape.  Tools should still be able to read it if it's read-only (plus you can check and change that on any OS) so more likely either the DBF is corrupt, or there is more than one feature in your shape file.  Where did you get the shapefile from anyway?  DBF should always be included, that's part of the standard.

Comment: Its doable - can you give a sample?

Comment: the shp was created using the api of shapelib. For some reasons, the dbf was not created.

Comment: yes, of course. how could I send the files?

Comment: dropbox, google-drive anything else

Comment: Thank you. here is the file: http://we.tl/2ijQN7RMsr I created the .dbf and .prj using r while the shp and shx were created by someoneelse using c++. The reason why I created a dbf with only one row is that I had thousands shapefiles with a different number of features so that I used the same dbf file for all of them.

Comment: "I had thousands shapefiles with a different number of features so that I used the same dbf file for all of them." - that isn't going to work.  The DBF file MUST have one row for each shape in the SHP file.

Comment: ok, many thanks for your time and help. then this is the problem. now I should understand how to create a dbf with the same number of features as the shp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shapefile you provided seems to be [valid](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html), and the projection in the prj files states (if im not mistaken) that your coordinates of each vertex are tied to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

Using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) [PGDump driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgdump.html) you can translate your shapefile to a sql querry that can be used to insert data into the database:

If you are in Windows you can open the console with `MSYS Shell`. It should be installed by default if you have used osgeo4w tool to install qgis.

Open your `msys` again and `cd` to your data directory, then for one file run:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f PGDump -lco schema=vectors -nln name -lco geometry_name=geom -lco fid=gid -lco srid=4326 temp.sql time_1057.shp
```

- the schema can be whatever you want.
- -nln is the name postgis table that will be created.
- the geometry_name and fid were choosen for compability reasons.
- the srid was extracted from your prj file.

you can use `head` to examine the header of the newly generated file to check what is goind to happen.

```
head temp.sql
```

In the header you can find information on what in going to happen when you execute the querry. eg how its going to create the tables, if an index is going to be created and etc... the rest of the file regards actual data that are going to be inserted to the table.

afterwards you can use `psql` to execute the sql file in your database. eg:

`psql -h IP -U USERNAME -f temp.sql`

Note that I didn't need any accompanied database files. The created table will contain data regarding the id (field name `gid` that we choose before) and the geometry information of the shape (field name `geom`). It's up to you to create and populate more fields fields.

Now since you mentioned that you have thousand of shapefiles, its a good idea to batch import them. Use again your Msys and `cd` to your data folder and use something like the following:

```
for f in $(ls *.shp); do 
      ogr2ogr.exe -f PGDump -lco schema=vectors -nln $(basename $f .shp) -lco geometry_name=geom -lco fid=gid -lco srid=4326 temp.sql $f;
      psql -h IP -U USERNAME -f temp.sql
```

After the operation completes, you should have a schema called vectors and within it a table for each shapefile you had

NB1: Don't forget to `VACUUM` afterwards to builds table statistics for the indexes to [work](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes).

NB2: There is a way to insert directly your data to the postgis, but i find if you use an intermediate file to do so, is easier to understand what's happening.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Very clear and complete answer. It works!