# saving .xls as .dbf...at a dead end

Tags: excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DBF creation and manipulation without excel 2003](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/dbf-creation-and-manipulation-without-excel-2003)

Hi -

I'm trying to convert an excel file to a shapefile in arview 3.3. using suggestions by Bill Huber (on the ESRI forums site).  I've completed the recommened 'recipe' of requirements on this link Bill  referred:

http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/GTKAV/section4/chapter_15a.htm#Recipe

but I am now stuck trying to convert .xls to .dbf because there is not an option in MS Excel 2007 to convert  to .dbf (dbase III or IV) that I can see - its all variations of .xls then .csv, .txt and other types.

Perhaps .csv is the file type I  need, but the 'recipe' says dbase III or IV, neither of which are listed  as options in excel.  Does anyone know  where to go from here?  If I can just get it to dbf I should be good (assuming my file formatting worked).

Answer (score 1):

See this thread for an answer: [DBF creation and manipulation without excel 2003](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/dbf-creation-and-manipulation-without-excel-2003)

Comment: Thanks so much.  Now for my next posting - the table, as opened in arcview - shows nothing even after the 'recipe' strictly and carefully followed. Any thoughts on that perhaps? (Diff't topic I realize  but I couldn't  resist!)